# Does time move faster on Sakaar?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok

In Thor: Ragnarok, the Grandmaster says

> "Time works real different around these parts. On any other world I would be millions of years old but here on Sakaar..." So GM confirms that time is doing *something* unusual on Sakaar, though he doesn't say what.

Also, we see that by the time Thor arrives on Sakaar,

> Loki has already been there some (three?) weeks, even though he was thrown out of the Bifrost no more than ~30 seconds before Thor was. If three weeks can pass for Loki on Sakaar when only ~30 seconds pass for Thor in the Bifrost before he is also thrown from it, that suggests that time moves about 60,000 faster on Sakaar. Is this what is "real different" about how time works, or is there something else? Additionally, if Hulk has been missing for 2 years on Earth, does that mean he has been on Sakaar for around 100,000 years?

Are there any supplementary materials such as tie-in comics or any of the stories that were adapted for the movie that suggest that might explain this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the Gamesmaster specifically says this in the movie, that time moves differently on Sakaar.

Comment: In the Planet Hulk, time was normal on Sakaar, it just had one end of a wormhole, the other end wandered around the universe, but the movie gave it a tonne of portals all over the place, and I thought it was just the portal was just really slow in delivering Thor.

Comment: If he'd be millions of years old elsewhere, and is Jeff Goldblum years old on Sakaar, surely that means time moves **slower** there, no?

Comment: That GE lighting is quite impressive

Comment: I don't know where you got your numbers from but it's actually 60,480x faster if 30 seconds to 3 weeks can be believed exactly

Comment: @Edlothiad Thanks! I fixed my numbers.

Comment: Do you think the actual question should be, 'Does time move differently inside the Bifrost?'? I haven't seen the movie yet, but I'm just wondering if you've drawn connections between two unrelated event's?

Comment: @Kwola-T The other two Thor movies never once suggested that time behaves differently in the Bifrost compared to the rest of the Nine Realms, while GM outright tells us that time moves differently on Sakaar.

Comment: Fair doos. TBH I'm probably better off watching the movie before commenting :)

Answer (score 4):

The Grandmaster is an Elder of the universe. He and others like him, e.g. the Collector, are ageless. So the Grandmaster may have very well meant that rather than being millions of years old by standard time, he is in fact billions of years old.

Comment: Welcome to SFF! I'm not entirely sure how this answers the question of "Does time move faster on Sakaar?" Could you [edit] to clarify?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot the elder has been alive since the creation of the universe. He should be billions of years old. If the is only millions of years old, then time passes slower on Sakaar.

Comment: @Renan Assuming the universe is as old in the MCU as it is in ours. I don't know too much of that sort of thing to know for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Loki reaching Sakaar weeks before Thor doesn't necessarily  imply that time runs faster on Sakaar. Inside Bifrost, Thor and Loki were moving faster than light across space-time and suddenly they got kicked out of it. We can't really predict/calculate which space-time points (just outside Bifrost beam) they both would hit after getting out (and, before picking a portal to Sakaar) because we don't have a theory, real or fictional. When you compare the ratios to calculate 60000x faster time, you actually assume that the relationship is linear. But, obviously this is not how universe works. Even real world time dilation effects don't work linearly.

As for Grandmaster's statement (For others, I am millions of years old, but here on Sakaar, I am..), this implies that time really runs at different rate on Sakaar.

> Faster or Slower?

We don't know as he didn't finish the sentence, but if he meant less than 100 (most likely; age of real world actor), time runs at slower rate on Sakaar. Otherwise, faster.

Comment: Downvoting because your answer doesn't make any sense. We know the spacetime points that they hit, the movie told us and I told you, so there is no need to "predict" them. You don't explain why my linear comparison "obviously" does not work to find the time dilation factor. And there's nothing to support your guess as to what the Grandmaster didn't say.

Comment: @JDoe Read that "predict" sentence in context. What I mean to say is: Sakaar might not have a different time rate and yet getting out of Bifrost could push Loki into past. We have no way to know (we can't predict/calculate that) because we have no theory.

Comment: BTW, I've edited that sentence to make it simpler. Hope it helps.

Answer (score -2):

While time may move faster on Sakaar, this may not affect the age of the inhabitants. The GrandMaster only says "time  works differently here." He doesn't say how. We can assume it speeds up time since Loki says he has been there 3 weeks as per Thor's 30 seconds during the bifrost battle. However they can be aging at the time of earth years. So if the GM spent 1 year on Earth, he would be able to get 60,000x the work done. So it would appear to him that he is 60,000 years old while to us he's just moving really fast. Like watching a DVD at 60,000x speed.

Comment: This answer starts off promising but then essentially develops into a fan theory. Can you provide any evidence that he would be moving incredibly fast if he visited Earth?