# How long was Hulk actually on Sakaar?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok

There seems to be a disconnect between what Thor tells Banner (he's been on Sakaar for two years, since the events of *Age of Ultron*) and what probably happened. We see that time moves faster on Sakaar than Earth or Asgard. This is first shown when Loki and Thor fall out of the Rainbow Bridge within seconds of each other, but Loki has been on Sakaar weeks before Thor arrives. Even the Grandmaster admits that time is different on Sakaar.

It seems likely to me that Hulk had actually been on Sakaar for decades, maybe even centuries. How long was Hulk on Sakaar before Thor arrived?

Comment: This is a duplicate of my question: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/173476/does-time-move-faster-on-sakaar?s=2|53.0017

Comment: It's not even entirely clear that there's consistent time *on Sakaar itself*, let alone enough of a reference to identify how fast time travels in other realms.

Comment: @J Doe I saw that question but missed the last sentence in the second spoiler box. You are correct that one of the questions you address is Hulk's length of time on Sakaar, and that this is a duplicate. I'll delete soon assuming this isn't closed first.

Comment: @SocioMatt - It can't be closed as a dupe because the other question doesn't have an upvoted answer

Comment: @Valorum So should I delete this or let it sit and see if it generates a better answer than the other?

Comment: @SocioMatt - Given that the other question is wider (and earlier), I'd suggest that you delete this one.

Comment: @SocioMatt Leave it open. Either it gets a good answer that's at least partially helpful to answering the other one, or it doesn't get an answer before the other one does and this can be closed as a duplicate then. This one has some different search criteria, so it's a useful signpost.

Answer (score 1):

The Hulk definitely was not on Sakaar for 2 years, considering that he had to travel through space for some time before he wound up being stuck there. But, regardless of that, the entire Sakaar plot is extremely inconsistent. They state that time moves differently there, and is this shown by Valkyrie being significantly older than Thor, as well as the differences in his and Loki's arrival. BUT! it becomes inconsistent when Thor speaks with Heimdall in real-time, and all of the events that happen on Sakaar coincide with the same time as the events that occur on Asgard.

It is mostly an unanswerable question because the movie itself gives two inconsistent versions of time between Sakaar and the rest of the universe. I'm sure they have noticed that themselves, but I think that entire movie was just meant to be a "fun" filler. The amount of time doesn't mean anything, and it's not something that can really be explained.

Comment: I believe the exact quote is _”Time works differently on Sakaar”_ it’s never fully explained so the inconsistencies you mention aren’t necessarily inconsistencies.